# Open Fragments through App Bar/Toolbar using Navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

I implemented a bottom navigation view which also handles multiple backstacks using Google's own workaround as given in the architecture components sample ,using the [file](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt)

```
private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
        val navGraphIds = listOf(
            R.navigation.blog,
            R.navigation.events,
            R.navigation.practice,
            R.navigation.login
        )

        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)
        val controller = bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
            navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
            fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
            containerId = R.id.fragment,
            intent = intent
        )

        //use this to setup Action bar

        controller.observe(this) { navController ->
            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
        }
        currentNavController = controller
    }
```

This is how I setup the bottom navigation view. I have an app bar which should open the settings fragment , but so far I have been unable to do so. Any solutions? This is how selecting the options should look like

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.settings -> TODO()//->should open settings fragment
        }
        return true
    }
```

I cannot directly navigate to settings as the current architecture has multiple nav graphs and as such it says,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.istemanipal.lumos:id/themeFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.istemanipal.lumos:id/blogFragment
```

Comment: Did you include your setting `Fragment` in your current nav graph?

Comment: You cannot just move to a fragment which is not a part of the nav graph using the controller which is why you're getting the exception. But, you can directly load the fragment using the `supportFragmentManager` without messing with the controller.

Comment: I have used a FragmentContainerView to load in the fragments. Does supportFragmentManager allow injection to it? Or am I missing something there?

Answer (score 0):

if the id of the menu item is set to the fragment id, you could probably use navigation controller to switch the destination.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.settings -> currentNavController.navigate(R.id.navigation_destination_id)
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: That does not work . It throws an IllegalArgumentException . It says:
Navigation action/destination com.istemanipal.lumos:id/settingsFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.istemanipal.lumos:id/blogFragment). This makes a lot of sense there are multiple nav graphs.

Comment: Do you add the destination fragment into res/navigation/{navigation graph}.xml with the id to be used with navigate function?

Comment: Yes. I defined a separate nav graph for this purpose. That failed. The only way to go is manually add this destination in the nav graph of each screen in the app and define the action . This is as you might imagine is not a good solution